# AngularJs error: "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"

Tags: angularjs

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4766/

I've written some basic angular code which actually works properly, and I get the desired result and ouput. However, I get some errors in my console which keep looping and eventually crash the browser. I've read some similar problems here, but can't seem to get a solution to work with my code.

Can anyone figure out what is going wrong and how to fix?

```
Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your function, you must return a stable object (or near stable). Because you `var` new objects in the `getBreakdown` function, angular thinks they're new and puts them in the scope with new hashkeys.

Angular then runs this `$digest` again, to check to make sure nothing has changed... but it sees new objects and assumes that the model is not stabalized. It runs it again... and gets new objects again... and again... and again.

The moral of the story is you shouldn't create new model inside a function assigned to scope.

If you don't need live-binding, just transform this var into a new $scope var just once, don't bind to the function. If you need live binding, I think the solution for you is to use a filter.

btw... add a `console.log(breakdown)` right before your function returns, inspect each object inside the array and you'll see it outputs 10 times, each `$$hashkey` value is different. Angular uses the `$$hashkey` to keep track of objects. I think it'll be easier to understand how you're confusing it.

The example I use to teach people this concept is a function that returns a random number. If you try to bind to that function... angular will digest it 10 times each time getting a new random number and never stablizing. Angular won't know it's done digesting... ever. So thats why they limit it to 10.

Comment: so I don't need the live binding, because I will call the function everytime I need the data to be updated. I've tried to transform the vars into $scope but with no luck. Do you mind updating my jsfiddle to show me?

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4767/ it just runs once when the controller starts. You'll need to call getBreakdown in your controller everytime it changes.

Comment: Sorry one more question, with this updated code, can I still pass a userId into the function, from the HTML?

Comment: When you bind from HTML, you create a $watch.. a live binding. So no, if you bind from HTML you will break it.

Comment: You could maybe create a function that just returns the count for a particular user, that doesn't create an objects. Then bind from that... ng-repeated through activities. No need for new model.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I want :)

Comment: Hi Jonatan, Didn't have any luck with this. Any chance I could get some help?